# swing drag&drop file transferable?

Tags: swing, file, drag-and-drop

I would like to drag and drop from my application into a system folder, so that when I drop an item, it shows up as a new file that represents the object I dragged.

What DataFlavor should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out myself. You just need to use [`DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaFileListFlavor) and create a temporary file somewhere, and it all works well. Here's what worked for me:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class FileTransferable implements Transferable 
{
    final private List<File> files;
    final private DataFlavor[] flavors;

    /**
     * A drag-and-drop object for transfering a file.
     * @param file file to transfer -- this file should already exist,
     * otherwise it may not be accepted by drag targets.
     */
    public FileTransferable(Collection<File> files) {
        this.files = Collections.unmodifiableList(
                new ArrayList<File>(files));
        this.flavors = new DataFlavor[] 
                { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor };
    }

    static FileTransferable createFileInTempDirectory(String filename) 
        throws IOException
    {
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File f = new File(dir, filename);
        f.createNewFile();
        return new FileTransferable(Collections.singletonList(f));
    }

    public List<File> getFiles() { return this.files; }

    @Override public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
            throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException 
    {
        if (isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
            return this.files;
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return this.flavors;
    }

    @Override public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor.equals(flavor);
    }
}
```