# Is there a way to do drag and drop in my Jtree?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

I have a Jtree and I need to drag and drop the nodes within the Jtree. That means, I should be able to drag node from any position in jtree and should be able to be drop it in any position that same Jtree.

This is the code I wrote for node transfer

```
    class TreeTransferHandler2 extends TransferHandler 
{
DataFlavor nodesFlavor;
DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];
DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodesToRemove;
@Override
protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
    JTree tree = (JTree)c;
    Object object = tree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
     if (object instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)
     {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) object;
         String toString = selectedNode.getUserObject().toString();
         return new StringSelection(toString);
     }
     return null;
}

@Override
public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
    return COPY_OR_MOVE;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not talking about window docking:

Yes, this is easy. Netbeans Platform is just an application framework for Swing. You can use all the **standard Swing DnD** techniques.

- Maybe you should read into a drag and drop tutorial like [that](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/209966-java-drag-and-drop-tutorial-part-1-basics-of-dragging/).
- For dropping files on the application you could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879956/swing-dragdrop-file-transferable).